# Union 'this' type with original 'this' type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In typescript, I can specific this type like this:

```js
let data = {
   prop1: "prop1"
}

let obj = {
    fun1(this: typeof data){
        this.prop1;  // works
        this.fun2(); // doesn't work
    },
    fun2(){}
}
```

But how can I declare 'this' type that I can make union with original 'this' type so I can write like `this.fun2()`, maybe something like `fun1(this: typeof _this | typeof data)`.

Comment: Separately, for `this` in `fun1` to refer to `obj`, `obj` would have to have `propOfA` ([example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-IAOUA9oQPIyoBcyIArgLYBG0A3LgL664A2EYZCWYArZAF5MuAshj0QARgAUYABbAAzrXQAyZGACehCCRhDRASil4ZBNZoB0xMpVRtkAeg-IA7iSgA1hrStvj2Gg5yIABMShbuXsgAJiQQGiAA5IJ+gSH4nAA0ebLysRYY3DicbEA)), but it doesn't. And if `obj` is `A`, it makes the union unnecessary. So I'm afraid it's really unclear what you're asking here. This seems like it's been simplified for the question to the point it's impossible to tell what you're really after.

Comment: `A` is not a problem in my question. It can be any types.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I edited it, is there any advice?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I checked your snippet, `this: A & typeof obj` surely not make sense as you explained. But if I don't specific 'this' type, I can call `this.fun2()` because ts infered 'this' type. So what I want is union these two types, both `A` and previously infered 'this' type...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```typescript
let data = {
    prop1: "prop1",
};

interface ObjType {
    fun1(this: (typeof data) | ObjType): void;
    fun2(): void;
}

let obj: ObjType = {
    fun1(this: (typeof data) | ObjType) {
        if ("prop1" in this) {
            this.prop1;  // works
        }
        if ("fun2" in this) {
            this.fun2(); // works
        }
    },
    fun2() {
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAJghmMQLwQN4FgBQFsQA4CcB7XARgC4IAiA4kygGkwF8BuTTASwDswR8AzGAGMQEAPIAjAFYAVAJ65R6LDn4BXLiQAUYABYcAzhR0KQhftDgwAlBAA+46fMXWKAN0IcobFdnVcAJi1XCA8vHyZ2DFBIQmkKSVlTJFRMHAh-bT1DYzBTc0t4WwdE5xBbZXT0jgstaiJSSghuCGyDCrSqrraAOhpSFmwAeiGIAHdCfABrA06uyN8qmog6-wCmlraOxa7sXrXgwZHxyZm5qoX0pkZFg+2r5iA)

(We need the type declaration because we can't use `typeof obj` in `obj`'s constructor if we don't have a type on it. Well, we can, but we get `any`.)

Note the need for type guards, because `this` could be `typeof data` (and so have `prop1`) **or** `ObjType` (and so have `fun2`). So we have to figure out which it is before using them.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it's a work around solution. I wondering is there any more elegant way to do this thing. I hate redecalre types that can be infered so easily...

Comment: @KFJK - Sadly I don't think you can in this case. [This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAJghmMQLwQN4FgBQFsQA4CcB7XARgC4IAiA4kygGkwF8BuTTUSQgIwCslUmHBABmAVwB2JABRgAFgEsAzhVkBPXCEIjocGAEoIAHwjrN2iD177D6LMJwKd06kVKUICiRHnLbQh0DfJQA6GlIWbAB6KIgAd0J8AGslAMCmNIcnU0pxCQAmDy8fRSV-e0DhYJC8-Ol9SJj4xJTM4QyKiCZGTtr6wU6OpiA) is the error you get: *"'obj' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.(7022)"*